# colMeans and Summary don't work

Tags: r, statistics

Good time
I'm a beginner and I have probplems with understanding R.
First, I can't see why `summary()` doesn't work with `data.frame` correctly
I have pretty big data table 2595x20, and read it this way:

```
table=read.table('data.txt')
statData <- data.frame(k1=table$V1[2:dim(table)[1]],       
                         k2=table$V2[2:dim(table)[1]], 
                         k3=table$V3[2:dim(table)[1]], 
                         k4=table$V4[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k5=table$V5[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k6=table$V6[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k7=table$V7[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k8=table$V8[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k9=table$V9[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k10=table$V10[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k11=table$V11[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k12=table$V12[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k13=table$V13[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k14=table$V14[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k15=table$V15[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k16=table$V16[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k17=table$V17[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k18=table$V18[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k19=table$V19[2:dim(table)[1]],
                         k20=table$V20[2:dim(table)[1]])
attach(statData)
```

and then using summary have the following:

```
> summary(statData)
           k1                 k2                 k3                  k4      
 2          :   3   0          :   9   0.419540527:   2   -0.092111263:   2  
 1.035054208:   2   0.000957854:   2   0.445687651:   2   -0.15798793 :   2  
 1.159481195:   2   0.004444444:   2   0.00982686 :   1   0           :   2  
 3.32231405 :   2   0.024900398:   2   0.041484213:   1   0.049426895 :   2  
 0.248322148:   1   0.029172089:   2   0.045053272:   1   0.699004975 :   2  
 0.284853052:   1   0.037267081:   2   0.046308725:   1   -0.002051282:   1  
 (Other)    :2584   (Other)    :2576   (Other)    :2587   (Other)     :2584
```

which has no sense to me.

colMeans accures an error:

```
> colMeans(statData)
Error in colMeans(statData) : 'x' must be numeric
```

but my data are definitely numeric.
As I understood it's because k1-k20 are factors. Well, but when I try to convert them with `as.numeric(levels(k1)[k1])` I have the different data that may be indexes I suppose.
So the question is how to make those functions work and work correctly may be changing the way of table reading or convirting, or something else?

Comment: Check the `str(statData)` or `sapply(statData, class)` to find if all the columns are `numeric`

Comment: Yeah, they are not numeric, I've wrote that
'data.frame': 2595 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ k1 : Factor w/ 2591 levels "0.248322148",..: 405 1808 12 2567 1652 2404 274 2398 1929 863 ...
 $ k2 : Factor w/ 2582 levels "0","0.000133032",..: 1353 2081 71 2414 248 2500 341 2486 1664 1379 ...
 $ k3 : Factor w/ 2594 levels "0.00982686","0.041484213",..: 1611 1938 40 2477 1907 2465 242 2372 1720 928 ...

Comment: Okay, so you have several `factor` class columns which are not `numeric`.  Convert it to `numeric`, i.e `i1 <- sapply(statData, is.factor); statData[i1] <- lapply(statData[i1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: Your data is not read in as numeric. There are non-numbers in your data, possibly encoding `NA` values. Fix your data import. That you try to remove the first row (in a very complicated and roundabout way)  indicates that you probably have column headers and should set `header = TRUE` in `read.table`.

Comment: ?read.table to learn more of its arguments. Probably the "sep=" needs to be checked in your file

Comment: @akrun, thanks a lot! :) it works perfectly!
so easy, sorry for bothering

Comment: @8txra Don't just fix the symptom. Fix the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can create an index for the `factor` columns, change the `class` to `numeric` and do the `colMeans`

```
i1 <- sapply(statData, is.factor)
statData[i1] <- lapply(statData[i1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
colMeans(statData)
```